# how to keep a running score in a textbox/object in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

My powerpoint is made is like a quiz, one slide has a question and 4 answers (buttons with text, not numbers) that can be clicked on. When an answer is clicked on, it is linked to another slide that explains if the answer being right/wrong and then adds/subtracts points from the score.

Currently what I have done is a simple macro that each button is linked to and upon clicking any of the 4 answer buttons, it will go to a certain slide and show a pop up box with their current score.

What I want to do is have either a text box or some object that holds the score throughout the entire presentation and ideally if possible, the score resets when the ppt is closed or opened but the running score is the most important aspect I'm trying to hammer down.

Is this possible for what I'm asking? Let me know if there are any details that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of resetting the score when the presentation shuts down, do it at startup.  For example, you could put a "Begin the quiz" button on the first slide, have it reset the score, then move to the next slide.

As to where to store the score, there are a number of ways of doing it. One would be to put a rectangle or text box on the last slide and store the score as its text.  Make sure the rectangle's sent to back so it's the first shape on the slide, or change Shapes(1) below to indicate the actual z-order position of the shape.

```
Function SetScore(lScore as Long)

Dim lLastSlide as Long

lLastSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

With ActivePresentation.Slides(lLastSlide).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
  .Text = Cstr(lScore)
End With

End Function
```

A companion GetScore function should be easy to come up with, similar to the above.

Comment: I used your work to play with the syntax and different possibilities until I got it exactly how I wanted it, thank you!